# Get range slider value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I create a 2-range slider with the code below, and now I don't know how can I refer to slider value in other functions.

````js
class Slider {
  constructor (rangeElement, valueElement, options) {
    this.rangeElement = rangeElement
    this.valueElement = valueElement
    this.options = options

    // Attach a listener to "change" event
    this.rangeElement.addEventListener('input', this.updateSlider.bind(this))
  }
  // Initialize the slider
  init() {
    this.rangeElement.setAttribute('min', this.options.min)
    this.rangeElement.setAttribute('max', this.options.max)
    this.rangeElement.value = this.options.cur
    this.updateSlider()
  }
  // Format the money
  asMoney(value) {
    return parseFloat(value)
      .toLocaleString('en-US', { maximumFractionDigits: 2 })
  }  
  generateBackground(rangeElement) {   
    if (this.rangeElement.value === this.options.min) {
      return
    }
    let percentage =  (this.rangeElement.value - this.options.min) / (this.options.max - this.options.min) * 100
    return 'background: linear-gradient(to right, #5433FF, #20BDFF, #A5FECB ' + percentage + '%, #d3edff ' + percentage + '%, #dee1e2 100%)'
  }
  updateSlider (newValue) {
    this.valueElement.innerHTML = this.asMoney(this.rangeElement.value)
    this.rangeElement.style = this.generateBackground(this.rangeElement.value)
  }
}
// First Slider
let firstSliderOptions = {
  min: 1000,
  max: 400000,
  cur: 100000
}
let firstRangeElement = document.querySelector('.range__slider--first [type="range"]')
let firstValueElement = document.querySelector('.range .range__value--first span') 
if (firstRangeElement) {
  let firstSlider = new Slider(
    firstRangeElement,
    firstValueElement,
    firstSliderOptions
  ) 
  firstSlider.init()
}
// Second slider
let secondSliderOptions = {
  min: 1,
  max: 60,
  cur: 24
}
let secondRangeElement = document.querySelector('.range__slider--second [type="range"]')
let secondValueElement = document.querySelector('.range .range__value--second span') 
if (secondRangeElement) {
  let secondSlider = new Slider(
    secondRangeElement,
    secondValueElement,
    secondSliderOptions
  )
  secondSlider.init()
}
```
````

I just want to use the value from the first range slider in an operation, and display the result of the operation in an HTML. Can you please help?

Comment: Your code is quite complex and shows that you know how to access HTML elements using the DOM. What trouble are you having updating the page with a value from your slider?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i have the slider value in my page, but i dont know how to use it in other functions in js

Comment: But in your code you are using the slider value in various functions. What is different about this new function?

Comment: Yes is a property of Slider class, but I don't know how to declare a variable in the respective class without it being a property of the class. And use this variable in a function outside of Slider class.